# Any mathematical tools to find the optimal shape to fit point cloud into

Tags: point-cloud

I have a point cloud and I have a couple of different geometric shapes like rectangle or circle. Are there any mathematical tools to find which one of the geometric shapes we could fit the point cloud into, in a way which would minimize the empty space inside the shape, i.e. space not covered by point cloud?

Comment: What are the size of the geometric shapes and the point cloud? If the point cloud can be fully contained by the geometric shapes, isn't the empty space just a measurement of the rest of area or numbers of pixels?

Comment: @Tab1e The dimensions of the rectangle and sphere are minimal required to fit the point cloud into. I'm not sure how to define the empty space.

Comment: You have to represent your geometric shapes by point cloud of corresponding geometric shapes. Otherwise, a finite set of points in Rn has measure zero.

Comment: As pointed out, minimizing the "empty area" is meaningless. Do you perhaps mean that you want to find the shape of smallest area that contains your cloud of points?

Comment: In any case, for a circle you can search for [Welzl's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem#Welzl's_algorithm) and for the smallest area rectangle [you can do it in linear time in two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms#Two_dimensions)